# SQL – Find all records in one table where linked records don’t exist

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a slight twist on the other “in one table but not another” threads I’ve seen.

I have 3 tables:

```
ProductFeed
    ProductFeedID INT
    ProductName NVARCHAR(30)

Product
    ProductID INT
    ProductFeedID INT
    StorefrontID INT

Storefront
    StorefrontID INT
    StorefrontName NVARCHAR(30)
```

- The ProductFeed table has one unique product per record.
- The Product table can have multiple of the same ProductFeedID, but can only have 0 or 1 unique ProductFeedID record per storefront.
- The Storefront table has 1 record per storefront.

What I wish to do is a query showing all ProductFeed records, with the StorefrontID and StorefrontName, which DO NOT contain a Product record for that storefront.  So something like this:

```
ProductFeedID   ProductName    StorefrontID     StorefrontName
   123             iPod             1              MyStore1
   123             iPod             4              MyStore4
   234             TShirt           2              MyStore2
   234             TShirt           4              MyStore4
   345             Coffee Mug       5              MyStore5
   etc.
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012.  Can someone help?

Comment: You'll want to use joins.  [Check out this reference](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) it will help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can approach this problem is by generating all possible combinations of product feeds and store fronts, then use `left join`.  The combinations that fail to match are the ones you want:

```
select pf.*, sf.*
from productfeed pf cross join
     storefront sf left join
     product p
     on p.ProductFeedID = pf.ProductFeedID and
        p.StoreFrontId = pf.StoreFrontId
where p.ProductId is null
```

Comment: Both answers do the trick.  The Cross Join is the key.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-- I think this is more understandable.

```
    select pf.*, sf.*
    from productfeed pf  
    cross join storefront sf 
    where not exists (select 1 
                      from product p
                      where p.ProductFeedID = pf.ProductFeedID
                      and p.StoreFrontID = sf.StoreFrontID)
```